# Callback é executada no parametro

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
function requestAjax(url, metodo, data, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: metodo,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        statusCode: {
            200: () => {
                successCallback();
            }
        }
    });
}

function adicionarNovaCategoria() {
    if ($("#nova-categoria-input").val() !== '') {
        var categoria = {
            nomeCategoria: $("#nova-categoria-input").val()
        };

        requestAjax("/api/categorias-componente", "POST", categoria, function () {
            showAlertaVerde("Item adicionado!");
            getTodasCategorias();
            $("#nova-categoria-input").val('');
        });

    } else {
        showNomeInvalido();
    }
}
```

A função que passo como callback no segunda função **adicionarNovaCategoria** é executa antes de entrar na função **requestAjax**.

Comment: Você não entendeu                                                                     ```showAlertaVerde("Item adicionado!");
            getTodasCategorias();
            $("#nova-categoria-input").val('');```                                                    
 é executado antes do ajax

Comment: Entendi agora. MAs testando aqui essas funções foram chamadas após o Ajax(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário setar o ajax para assíncrono false.

async: "false"

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado!